# Using awk command in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, awk, gawk

I'm trying to loop an awk command using bash script and I'm having a hard time including a variable within the single quotes for the awk command. I'm thinking I should be doing this completely in awk, but I feel more comfortable with bash right now.

```
#!/bin/bash

index="1"

while [ $index -le 13 ]
do

    awk "'"/^$index/ {print}"'" text.txt

done
```

Comment: Why not just `grep "^$index"` ? Seems like using awk for this purpose is over the top...

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard approach -- `-v` option of `awk` to set/pass the variable:

```
awk -v idx="$index" '$0 ~ "^"idx' text.txt
```

Here i have set the variable `idx` as having the value of shell variable `$index`. Inside `awk`, i have simply used `idx` as an `awk` variable.

`$0 ~ "^"idx` matches if the record starts with (`^`) whatever the variable `idx` contains; if so, print the record.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/'"$index"'/' text.txt
# A lil play with the script part where you split the awk command
# and sandwich the bash variable in between using double quotes
# Note awk prints by default, so idiomatic awk omits the '{print}' too.
```

should do, alternatively use `grep` like

```
grep "$index" text.txt # Mind the double quotes
```

<sub>**Note :** `-le` is used for comparing numerals, so you *may* change `index="1"` to `index=1`.</sub>

Comment: `'/'"$index"'/'` this is bad practice, use `-v varname="somevalue"` instead